# How to find text node after an element using CSS Selector?

Tags: css, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, testcafe

I've the below HTML content and I want to read the text "Component" using CSS Selector (not XPath). Is there a way to read this text in this scenario ?
I tried appending "+ #text" to the CSS Selector of its sibling "p class='abc'" but no luck.

```
    <div class='section'>
       <p class='abc'>Product</p>
       "Component"
       <p class='xyz'>Date</p>
       "01-01-2023"
    </div>
```

Comment: AFAIK, CSS selectors cannot select text nodes. Why would you want to do that?